# Import Paper Responces to Google Form

Tags: google-sheets

I have a survey which most people will complete on a printed form and want to know if there is a way to then scan this in and have a program pick up the responses to then collate this information without having to manually type every response. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best place to start would be some research on OCR. It wouldn't be a Google Sheets native feature.